# Replacing DOM elements that are dynamic

Tags: dom, dynamic, replace

I have a dynamic list **< li >**

```
<li>The user name "marcus001" is already taken.</li>
```

I need to replace this whole line with:

```
<li><p>Thank you for your registration</p></li>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, I have tried to replace this whole DOM, but because the username "marcus001" is dynamic, it always fails to target.

Notes:

This is generated by a system so there are no **id's** associated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using id attribute to target the `<li>`

```
<li id="message">The user name "marcus001" is already taken.</li>
```

Change it using javascript

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<p>Thank you for your registration</p>";
```